# Install numpy+mkl through gohlkegrabber

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-wheel

I've been trying to install numpy+mkl from [Christope Gohlke Python Library](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) through gohlkegraber package. However, I found no success to obtain numpy+mkl. Instead, I get numpy+vanilla. I install the package in virtualenv on windows 10 using the gohlke graber cli tool.
My command is `ggrab -v 1.19 . numpy`. Before trying that command I also try specify python version,platform, and abi such as `ggrab -v 1.19 -pf win64 -p 3.9 -a cp39m . numpy` but the ggrab return `unable to find a matching package version`. If I change the `numpy` to `numpy+mkl` I get `Could not download "numpy+mkl", possibly it is not available, or in the "Misc" category.` So, how to get numpy+mkl for my specified python version & platform correctly using gohlkegraber ?

Comment: I can't see a numpy wheel for version `1.19` and python `3.9` at https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy, so I guess this is the reason gohlkegrabber can't download it

Comment: I also try not including the pyhton version such `ggrab -v 1.19 -a cp39m -pf win64 . numpy` and `ggrab -v 1.19 -pf win64 . numpy`. Strangely, all of these comments return `unable to find a matching package version`. If I do `ggrab -v 1.19 . numpy` I get the vanilla numpy 1.19

Comment: I guess it should be `win_amd64` instead of `win64`. Maybe `ggrab -v 1.19.5+mkl . numpy` will get you the mkl version? (untested, just a hunch)

Comment: still out of luck. In addition I also try `ggrab -v 1.19+mkl . numpy`